# Self-compiled OpenVPN won't start from systemd

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, openvpn, services

I have compiled openvpn from source, running `openvpn --version` returns:

```
OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Nov 19 2017
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
```

And created a `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` file with some basic settings. However, when I try to start it with `sudo systemctl start openvpn@server` it returns

```
Failed to start openvpn@server.service: Unit openvpn@server.service not found.
```

And `sudo systemctl status openvpn` returns:

```
● openvpn.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2017-11-19 14:21:06 HKT; 4 days ago
 Main PID: 1502 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Which makes me think that openvpn service is not even registered.

I have checked `/lib/systemd/system/`, it doesn't have `openvpn.service` file, but `/etc/systemd/system/` does. As I understand this is because I compiled instead of `apt-get install openvpn`?

Can anyone suggest how should I add self-compiled openvpn as a service?

First time compiling from source, so any advise/tips much appreciated!

EDIT 1:

I can start openvpn server and connect clients to it with (only service doesn't seem to work):

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

Comment: your best bet is to install the official package and inspecting/using the official  files.

Comment: Can you post the output of `openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf`?I think you need to update your systemd files accordingly to match with the paths and settings of your self-compiled version.

Comment: Hey @WilliamSandin, `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf ` starts the openvpn server, I am able to connect clients. Only the systemctl doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Made it work by manually creating two files in `/lib/systemd/system`.

The first one is `openvpn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and second is `openvpn@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN connection to %i
PartOf=openvpn.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=openvpn.service
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
KillMode=mixed
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/%i.pid
PIDFile=/run/openvpn/%i.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn
ProtectSystem=yes
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating them, do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the new changes.

Generally, the files are the same, as if openvpn was installed from official repo, the only difference is `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn` should be `ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/openvpn`, pointing to compiled local openVPN.

Edit:
If you use openvpn 2.4+, remove `PIDFile=/run/openvpn/%i.pid` and `--writepid /run/openvpn/%i.pid` from the second file, as it prevents server from starting on boot. Found it [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1435831#c9)

Answer (score 3):

Updating from answer by Ilya (I don't have reputation to comment)

I have it working on Ubuntu 16.04 by using the provided service as a template (so a single service file), changing two things:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/openvpn-2.4.8/distro/systemd/openvpn-client@.service.in /lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service

sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service
```

Change:

- @sbindir@ to /usr/local/sbin/
- Type=notify to Type=simple

Reload and Start

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
service openvpn-client@client.service restart
service openvpn-client@client.service status
```

This assumes you've already got your config in /etc/openvpn/client/client.service.conf

Comment: If this is for the server, why do you copy the `openvpn-client.service`?  How can a client be a service? I don't understand that. Why didn't you copy `openvpn-server@.service.in`?  Thanks

Comment: indeed - I used this for a client - not server.